# Swift OSX Fullscreen hiding status and dock

Tags: swift, macos, menu, fullscreen, dock

is there a way to hide (not disable) OS X status bar and dock during fullscreen mode?

i have this code:

```
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    /* Pick a size for the scene */
    if let scene = MainMenuScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

            if let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen() {

                window.setFrame(screen.frame, display: true, animate: true)
                 window.collectionBehavior = NSWindowCollectionBehavior.FullScreenPrimary

 }

NSApplicationPresentationOptions.AutoHideMenuBar
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false


        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        self.skView!.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

but i get this error :

```
  Failed to set (collectionBehavior) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow)
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: What if you set `NSWindowCollectionBehavior.FullScreenPrimary` after the window has appeared?

Comment: i tried put NSWindowCollectionBehavior.FullScreenPrimary in didmovetoview of MainMenuScene.swift file...but no luck, menu bar and dock are still visible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hav you tried calling `self.window?.toggleFullScreen(true)` in the windowController?

e.g.

```
class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        self.window?.toggleFullScreen(true)
    }
}
```

Which starts full-screen with no menu-bar at the top nor dock.

or at least, `something.window?.toggleFullScreen(true)` where `true` should be the sender.

Comment: Your second option 'window?.toggleFullScreen(true)'  is perfect. with first,instead, menu bar and dock still remain visible.

Comment: That's probably because you haven't set the WindowController's class to WindowController, hence the `self.` reference

Comment: @AdrianSluyters, how can you resize the view inside of the window?